# How to push my edits of a cloned Github repo to my own repo?

Tags: git, github

I cloned an existing Github repo, then created a new repo on my own account, did `git remote add other <my-new-repo-URL>`, and `git push -u other master`. What appears when I look at the new pushed project on Github is a copy of the project that I pulled, without any of the edits I added. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Did you commit your edits ?

Comment: Yep I committed everything

Comment: You also can use the fork button on github to clone another repository to your own account.

Comment: What does `git status` say ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the steps you did to ["*commit everything*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477865/how-to-push-my-edits-of-a-cloned-github-repo-to-my-own-repo#comment105132994_59477865).

Make sure that you did indeed commit your changes before `push`-ing to `other`.

```
$ git clone <old-repo-url>

$ cd old-repo
$ (add/edit files) 
$ git add .
$ git status
$ git commit -m "Edited some files"
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
...

$ git remote add other <new-repo-url>
$ git push -u other master
```

Make sure also that you are committing on the correct branch. Maybe you committed on a different branch, but you are only pushing the `master` branch to the `other` repo.

You can try `push`-ing a different branch or [`--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all) instead.

```
$ git branch
$ git remote add other <new-repo-url>
$ git push other --all
```